# How to disable tabs from the activities inside the tabs in Android

Tags: android, tabactivity

My application has a TabActivity which contains 4 tabs. Each tab contains the corresponding activities.

The activity in the first tab is the Boot Activity. Based on some conditions I have to enable/disable the other 3 tabs from this Activity.

Can anyone help in enabling/disabling tabs from activities inside the tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are talking about hiding a tab.
Then use the following

Get `TabHost` from resource as

```
TabHost  tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

Then runtime use this

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Supposing that you are trying to hide 4th Tab.(So 3 is used)

Comment: hi Tanmay . thanks for the reply. the problem is i want to disable the tab2 and tab3 and tab4 from the Activity present inside the Tab1.

Comment: I have shown you how to disable  a tab.Now use it as you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3).setEnabled(false)
```